# Deploy a Django Application to Digital Ocean - Gunicorn Error

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my first app to digital ocean with help of this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html).

When I try to run sudo supervisorctl restart [appname], I get the following error.  (This is only a part of the error)

```
     [2019-01-16 09:10:49 +0000] [2653] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/productUploader/shadesProductUploader/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/srimal/django_project/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authSection'
```

My setup in the server is

[image]

and the supervisor config file

```
#!/bin/sh
[program:productUploader]
command=/home/srimal/django_project/bin/gunicorn_start
user=srimal
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/srimal/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

and the gunicorn_start file

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="productUploader"
DIR=/home/srimal/django_project
USER=srimal
GROUP=srimal
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/srimal/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=productUploader.shadesProductUploader.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=productUploader.shadesProductUploader.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source /home/srimal/django_project/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec /home/srimal/django_project/bin/gunicorn    ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
 --name $NAME \
 --workers $WORKERS \
 --user=$USER \
 --group=$GROUP \
 --bind=$BIND \
 --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
 --log-file=-
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Publish your productUploader.shadesProductUploader.settings file, you probably missed installing a dependency or adding it to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: setting.py file is under  shadesProductUploader folder. and I will add only the installed app section as the full file is too long for stackoverflow.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'authSection',
    'mainSection',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: Does the `productUploader` folder contain an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the `productUploader` directory is a python package, based on the fact that you're passing it in the dotted path to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE`. Thus you should also do the same for the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'productUploader.authSection',  # Use full path
    'productUploader.mainSection',  # Use full path
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions', 
    'django.contrib.messages', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```